# After input in textarea cant scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want make that, on input my chat content scrolls down, because my textarea expanding and hide last message. But now I get one problem, that I cant scroll up after input. There's my jQuery

```
$('.text-message textarea').on("keyup",function(){
    $(".chat_content").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Any solutions, why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead so your `.chat-content` would always automatically scroll to buttom on load and when new meaasge is displayed

```
var chat_content = $('.chat_content');
    chat_content.scrollTop(chat_content.prop("scrollHeight"));
```

**EDIT**

But you can also do this to scrollto your last message and `setInterval` to try to scroll down every 2 seconds

```
setInterval(function () {
        var chat_content = $('.chat_content');
        chat_content.animate({scrollTop: chat_content.prop("scrollHeight")}, 2000);
    }, 2000);
```

Hope this works